# Jquery - Move Div around

Tags: jquery, css

I am using Jquery Drag and drop to move divs across a page and this works perfectly.  however what i would like is on each one of the div containers is to have a close button which when clicks removes the div from where it is and places it in a pre-defined div at the bottom like a widget gallery.

How would this be accomplished? - below is my html..  thanks

Chris

```
<div class='column' id='leftcolumn'></div>

<div class='column' id='rightcolumn'>

    <div class='dragbox'>
      <span class='close'>Close</span>
Content In here
    </div>
</div>

<div class='column' id='widgetgallery></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.dragbox > span.close').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().appendTo("#widgetgallery");
});
```

Comment: So do you need to remove the div or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.close').click(function(){
  $('#widgetgallery').append($(this).parent());
  $(this).parent().delete();
});
```

I dunno if the appending part will work tough.

Comment: Is there a method named delete in jQuery?

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't need to `.remove()` it anyway... you've appended it